# Python plots display inline successfully but not using qt

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib

Using a python package called [quantstats](https://github.com/ranaroussi/quantstats), I'm able to plot successfully to the inline Plots pane in Spyder, but when changing matplotlib backend to qt, nothing is displayed.  Working in Ubuntu 22.04, Spyder 5.3.3, Python 3.9 and the most recent version of the package.

Have taken a look at the [codebase](https://github.com/ranaroussi/quantstats/blob/fa0a91a42400978bcc95f5f2fb2cf20e6f7af56c/quantstats/_plotting/wrappers.py#L672) and it's not clear to me what would cause this.  Any thoughts?

```
import quantstats as qs
%matplotlib inline

stock = qs.utils.download_returns('SPY')

# this successfully plots to inline pane
qs.plots.drawdown(stock)

# this completes without error, but doesn't display anything (aside from a momentary flash of a pop-up with 'Figure 1'
%matplotlib qt
qs.plots.drawdown(stock)
```

Comment: Does the issue happen only when *switching* the backend, or also when setting the Qt backend from the beginning? I've never used Spyder, but I know it's based on IPython, and Qt requires event loop processing (which is normally achieved by calling `%gui qt` if it's not set natively).

Comment: @musicamante, happens both the first time set, and running again having set it to `qt`.

Comment: Did you try to call the above mentioned command?

Comment: @musicamante, just did...same as before (flash of the new figure, but doesn't stay)

Comment: It's a bug of Quantstats. See [this](https://github.com/ranaroussi/quantstats/issues/320). Did you report it? Then, why did you post here?

Comment: As you can see at [here](https://github.com/ranaroussi/quantstats/blob/0.0.62/quantstats/_plotting/core.py#L395), the current implementation does not support the qt backend.